# HttpClient SendAsync from ASP .NET Core blocking calls down stack in Web API 2/Delphi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, delphi, asp.net-web-api2, delphi.net

Hope I can get the point across here..

I have 2 Workflows:

1. (Test-Success) (c).NET WebAPI REST endpoint > (d)WebRequest to > (e)another .NET WebAPI REST endpoint > (f)Delphi.NET library
2. (Fails): (a)ASP.NET 5 Core REST endpoint > (b)HttpClient.SendAsync >  (c)WebAPI REST endpoint> (d)WebRequest to > (e)another .NET WebAPI REST endpoint >  (f)Delphi.NET library  (blocks when calling the underlying Delphi method)

(2) is target state. From (c) onwards, it exactly the same as 1).

- In (2) Fiddler shows that correct url/headers are passed at (c) to the .WebAPI REST endpoint - but it never returns until the ASP.NET Core call (b) times out.

Things tried (not exhaustive)

- added ConfigureAwait(false) all way down the stack
- rewriting .NET Framework code to use HttpClient
- adding Async in the code calling Delphi.NET
- Removing async in HttpClient calls
- Adding EnableCors in Startup for the final endpoint
- Tried increasing and decreasing timeouts (on client and server)
- ConsoleApp to simplify the process

Standard Code to use HttpClient

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:xxxxx");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("header1", "xxx");


        var uri = $"{client.BaseAddress}v1/CoreEndpoint";
        string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("{body}");

        var m = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(uri), Method = HttpMethod.Post };
        m.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(m);
```

Comment: Please show the complete (a)(b).

Comment: (a) is a standard Controller method with POST which calls (b) as above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a missing slash:

```
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:xxxxx");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("header1", "xxx");


    var uri = $"{client.BaseAddress}v1/CoreEndpoint";
```

=> http://localhost:xxxxxv1/CoreEndpoint

Does it work if you change it to:

```
    var uri = $"{client.BaseAddress}/v1/CoreEndpoint";
```

Comment: BaseAddress adds in the slash, but good spotting. In production HttpClient is added in startup like client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{host}:{port}"); and then $"{_httpClient.BaseAddress}internal returns host/internal